# Xamarin the ResolveLibraryProjectImports task failed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting an error in my Xamarin.Forms application

I've tried cleaning, rebuilding solution. Didn't change anything.

I've tried disabling Use Fast Deployment in Android Options and that didn't change anything either.

Tried deleting bin and obj folders, also had no impact.

What's causing this error and how do I fix?

Full error below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'AB2goXamarin, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'AB2goXamarin.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5809/22d97e15/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 229
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5809/22d97e15/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 169
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AB2goXamarin.Android
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is the version of VS? Maybe you need upgrade.

Comment: Often this "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" error will be accompanied by another build error, in this case for the "AB2goXamarin" library itself that indicates a reason that the "AB2goXamarin" library failed to build. If you haven't yet, be sure to double-check for any compilation errors on the "AB2goXamarin" library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error after installing MVVMLight, but it disappeared after I updated my Visual Studio to newest version (VS Enterprise v15.6.1) and created new project again from template.